# /usr/bin/env -0 for non-Linux systems

Tags: environment-variables

Consider I want to programmatically read the environment of an interactive shell. Now, starting a shell, running `/usr/bin/env` and capturing its output seems like a good solution. But only up until the moment we realize that variable values can have line breaks:

```bsh
$ export LINE0='VALUE0
> LINE1=VALUE1'
$ env | grep ^LINE
LINE0=VALUE0
LINE1=VALUE1
```

So capturing the output of `env -0` (`NULL`-separated entries) seems like a better approach, but this only applies to GNU `env`, so is mostly Linux-specific.

Is there any portable (POSIX or BSD) way to get the `NULL`-separated list of environment variables, using only the standard command line tools (may use `awk`, but no `perl`/`python`/`ruby` allowed)?

Comment: That's a shame, because portable but not standardized tools exist.  [`printenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/printenv.xml) for just one example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how you plan to *restore* that captured environment, since no shell but zsh supports nul bytes in its variables.

Anyways, you could use `awk` to escape `\` as `\\` and the newline as `\n`, and still use a newline to separate the `name=val` entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  for(e in ENVIRON){
    v = e "=" ENVIRON[e];
    gsub(/\\/, "&&", v); gsub(/\n/,"\\n",v); print v
  }
}'
```

```
fzd$ env - $'foo\\bar\nquux=foo\\bar\nquux' lol=cat printenv
lol=cat
foo\bar
quux=foo\bar
quux

fzd$ env - $'foo\\bar\nquux=foo\\bar\nquux' lol=cat awk 'BEGIN{
  for(e in ENVIRON){
    v = e "=" ENVIRON[e];
    gsub(/\\/, "&&", v); gsub(/\n/,"\\n",v); print v
  }
}'
foo\\bar\nquux=foo\\bar\nquux
lol=cat
```

Comment: Thanks! I need a portable way to _read_, not a portable way to _restore_ =)

Comment: @Bass please see the simplified version (no functional change)

Comment: Thanks again! Actually, what I needed was an even simpler one-liner: `BEGIN { for (key in ENVIRON) { printf "%s=%s\0", key, ENVIRON[key] }}`

Comment: @Bass that doesn't work with all versions of awk, unfortunately. AFAIK only GNU awk (gawk) can handle nul bytes in its data. In particular, the default awk on Debian, *BSD and busybox-based systems like OpenWRT will not print the `\0`.